# Can we have a rounded corner without applying masktobounds

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Any possibility in having a rounded corner for a view container without using `masksToBounds = true` ?

```
signup.layer.cornerRadius = 10
signup.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Comment: im setting the cornerRadius for the subview. and an element passes through the subview to the main view

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you may have to write following code:

```
    let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 100.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    let aPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: containerView.bounds, cornerRadius: 10.0)
    aPath.lineWidth = 1.0
    aPath.stroke()

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.path = aPath.cgPath

    containerView.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    self.view.addSubview(containerView)
```